# ping test is always returning False

Tags: python

I am running the following ping test and it always returns False.  from the cli on the same machine I ping the host and it replies, but when I run the python script it doesnt work.  Not sure what I am missing?  I have tried to set the number of pings higher and it has no effect.  The host is a Debian box.  I have removed the suppresion and I see it pinging the host and it is replying, but eventually it returns with a False.  I have tried hostnames and IP's.

```
def myping(host):
    print(f"pinging {host}")
    response = subprocess.run(["ping", "-c", "2", f"{host}"])
               #stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
               #stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

print(myping("10.21.30.2"))
```

response with a valid IP:

```
pinging 10.21.30.2
PING 10.21.30.2 (10.21.30.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.21.30.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.478 ms
64 bytes from 10.21.30.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.476 ms

--- 10.21.30.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1019ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.476/0.477/0.478/0.001 ms
False
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything from your function.  Did you mean to `return response`?  Also, did you check the man page?  When `ping` succeeds, it returns 0, as is common with Unix commands.

Comment: By the way the recommended way is: `cmd = f"ping -c 2 {host}"; process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE); output, error = process.communicate()`

Comment: That is certainly not the "recommended" way if all you need is the exit status.  `run` was designed for that.  And it's always recommended to pass the parameters as a list instead of forcing subprocess to split them.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please read [ask] and [mre], as well as the relevant [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run). The code in the function shown here does not `return` anything, so `print` would naturally display `None` instead. `subprocess.run` returns an instance of a custom type, not a boolean value; and has done so since 3.5 when it was introduced.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen, that approach is the opposite of recommended. Using `cmd.split()` introduces bugs you don't have with a manual split operation; it's an outright antipattern. (In particular, someone can add extra arguments into a "hostname" without it being detected as an error; that's not _so_ awful for `ping`, but for commands that provide arguments to specify output files, it gets into security-impacting territory).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your feedback and information. I thought that having an explicit command string is much more readable, hence preferred, but guess, I was wrong.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen, the thing is that creating a string and then splitting it is _not_ "explicit": you're letting the boundaries be inferred from where the spaces are. Real shell processing is more complex than `str.split()`: `echo "hello world"` becomes `["echo", "hello world"]`, not `["echo", '"hello', 'world"']` as the split operation makes it. The _explicit_ thing is to specify the word boundaries directly: on UNIXlike operating systems, the native format for a command line is an array of C strings, not a shell command string; the string is just an abstraction for human use.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen, ...read `man execve` and `man posix_spawn` -- those are the two (traditional and modern) interfaces used to start programs on UNIX; a call to `system(somestring)` eventually becomes something like `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", somestring, NULL)`. The closer you are to specifying what should be passed to the underlying operating syscall, the more explicit your code is, and the fewer things are happening behind your back.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you soo much for those amazing reads ! Have a nice day sir :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Also I apologize for replying so late, today was Eid-ul-Azha so was busy :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually inspect your response and `return` a value based on whether it indicates that the operation was a success.

As with all Python functions, the default return value is `None`, which is treated as `False` when evaluated as a boolean.

```
def myping(host):
    print(f"pinging {host}")
    response = subprocess.run(["ping", "-c", "2", str(host)])
    return response.returncode == 0
```